# How to calculate points for f(nx) when all that's given for f(x) are arbitrary points

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics

If you have a point list for $f(x)$, how do you determine the point list for $f(nx)$?

The way I would have done it would be to plot the points for $f(x)$, identify the function and calculate the intercepts and offsets, and then plug in $(nx)$ into the function. The problem I have is that the point list seems completely arbitrary. Here's the question:

> The table below shows the values for the function $y=f(x):$
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline x&y\\ \hline
>  -4&7\\ \hline
>  -1&-2\\ \hline 0&3\\ \hline 3&-4\\ \hline 6&5\\ \hline \end{array}
>
> Complete the table for the function $y=f\left(\frac{1}{5}x\right)$.

The table that needs to be completed for $y=f\left(\frac{1}{5}x\right)$ is completely empty. It has 5 empty rows with two columns assigned for $x$ and $y$.

The plotted points draw a slanted W. I haven't been able to find any solution in Google because I'm not even sure what terms to search.

Comment: When the scaling factor augments $x$ (as in $f(nx)$ as opposed to $nf(x)$), you simply need to divide each $x$ by $n$ and keep the corresponding $y$ values the same. Essentially, the graph is compressed. If $0<\left|n\right|<1$, the graph gets stretched. If $\left|n\right|>1$, the graph gets compressed. If $n<0$, in addition to being compressed or stretched, the graph gets flipped horizontally.

Comment: How do the y values remain the same? If f(x) = x^2 and y = f(x) then 2^2 is not equal to (2*2)^2.The graph becomes steeper, but the y values are all changed.Is there some reference I could look to tell if we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: Are you trying to find $y$ values for the new function with the same $x$ values given?

Comment: My task is to complete the table. The table has 2 columns and 5 rows with x and y as the column headers.

Comment: The only points you can find with the information given are at $5x$ for each $x$ in the original table. At $5x$ values, the $y$ values for each stay the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: At 5x the f(⅕x) would equal all the same values as f(x). Ok. It makes sense now, and seems really obvious. It's just like you said, which I didn't understand before. The points we could plot for f(⅕x) would be (-20,7),(-5,-2),(0,3),(15,-4),(30,5). Thank you. If you make it an answer I would check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the scaling factor augments $x$ (as in $f(nx)$ as opposed to $nf(x)$), you simply need to divide each $x$ by $n$ and keep the corresponding $y$ values the same. Essentially, the graph is compressed. If $0<|n|<1$, the graph gets stretched. If $|n|>1$, the graph gets compressed. If $n<0$, in addition to being compressed or stretched, the graph gets flipped horizontally. Particularly in your case:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x&y\\ \hline
-20&7\\ \hline
-5&-2\\ \hline
0&3\\ \hline
15&-4\\ \hline
30&5\\ \hline
\end{array}